# Fading top and bottom of div element

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I've been able to fade the top of a div, but I can't get the bottom to fade as well. I figured I could just reverse the css I used to fade the top but it's not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-city">
  <div id="gradient-top">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 60px;">LOCATIONS</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="gradient-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-city {
  background-image: url("img/1652.png");
  width: 100%;
}

#gradient-top {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=0);
}

#gradient-bottom {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(1, 255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(1, 255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(1, 255, 255, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 255) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

**Question:**

Is there an easier way to accomplish this by fading the top and bottom?

**Current Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the simplest solution would be to add a `linear-gradient` with multiple stops to the `background-image` and center the title vertically and horizontally to get the effect you are looking for (you can also add percentage values to the gradient color stops to tweak how it fades). Something like the following:

```css
.container-background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, transparent, #fff), url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x800/f0f000/fff?text=');
  width: 100%;
}

.container-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-background">
    <h2 class="container-title">TITLE</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Just an FYI you can actually combine them into one element.

Comment: @jhpratt thanks for the tip, figured out how to combine the `linear-gradient` and `background-image` into the same element (including `linear-gradient` before `url` in the css was what I was missing the first time). Edited my answer to reflect your comment.